# updating the public key via the api constantly fails with EncryptionPublicKeyInvalidFormat

Tags: google-api, google-email-audit-api

Please see the results below from the oauth2.0 playground.   I followed the instructions from the page ( https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth#generating_key ) and it is constanty failing.  it used to work fine, but all of a sudden just started to always return that error.

OAUTH2.0 Playground request and response

---

```
POST /a/feeds/compliance/audit/publickey/dev-gpanel.com HTTP/1.1
Host: apps-apis.google.com
Content-length: 2575
Content-type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlvnBOXmj9AOc72S35vnaLC5AL_3G-YOExMjbVWapS0WWKbR0g7Ec7b5xPiGD57bgAzFHs_yRhQwXDjS2YuXGqU8WK-NeLq-LoF5ghd5C4c7z0DER9ucJLoTF47i
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
<apps:property name="publicKey" value="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"/>
</atom:entry>
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 2601
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 14:49:08 GMT
Server: GSE
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 14:49:08 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
Content-type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
  <error errorCode="1411" invalidInput="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" reason="EncryptionPublicKeyInvalidFormat" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>
```

---

Has anyone else been seeing this?

***UPDATE****
Just tried this again and it failed with the same error.  Here's another request / response.

OAUTH2.0 Playground request and response

---

```
POST /a/feeds/compliance/audit/publickey/dev-gpanel.com HTTP/1.1
Host: apps-apis.google.com
Content-length: 2538
Content-type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer ya29.Glv-BBt27Xz0G3z9BBlA19poa4QxDaIRVc_pOqCZGQFYXDFzt4-HcBhuFRjpD0ue8NHNkZVQ99YG2Tn9FJ4vJR5vZqD4sYTwrnYGXu_64ifEPV_Kh3aRG-_yx-jH
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
<apps:property name="publicKey" value="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"/>
</atom:entry>
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 2544
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:44:26 GMT
Server: GSE
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:44:26 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
Content-type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
<error errorCode="1801" invalidInput="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" reason="InvalidValue" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>
```

---

Comment: Have you tried redoing the process all over again?

Comment: Hi, Yeah, we've tried multiple times.  I'll give it another go on Monday, but again, no code has changed, and the process has worked fine for months, if not years.

Comment: Just tried it again ( 5 times with different keys ) and it failed everytime.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hey All, anyone else running into this?  I just tested it again with the same result, below is the request / response from the OAuth 2.0 playground.

Comment: Hey All, just tried it again with no luck.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @mike.schlanser Hi Mike, have you find solution for this problem? I have followed all the instructions in the document with no luck.

Comment: @darkfolcer No, we didn't change anything and it started working again.  Not sure what the problem was, but it seems like it was a problem on the Google side of things.